# How to validate an object with unknown properties in RunTypes (typescript lowercase object)

Tags: typescript, runtypes

I just want to validate object and have written:

```
export const ExternalLinks = Record({})
```

Is it proper? I ask regarding the repository.

Comment: I don't understand.  What you have written is correct syntax as long as `Record` is callable.  You'll need more detail if you're asking something else.

Comment: But how to say that I just want to have there object?

Comment: can you provide more details? are you talking about runtypes library?

Comment: Yes, I talk about runtypes library, I just want to validate object, any object. That is it.

Comment: So just [`:object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct to do that.  If you define a runtype in this way it will accept anything. For example:

```
const MyRecordRuntype = Record({}); 

type MyRecord = Static<typeof MyRecordRuntype>; // {}

const greeting: MyRecord = 'Oh hai, Mark!';

const inquiry = "What's new with you?";

MyRecordRuntype.guard(inquiry); // true
```

I think you want to define a type like the following:

```
type MyRecord = { [key: string]: unknown };
```

I don't know how to do this with `runtypes` either.  An alternative way to do this would be to use `io-ts` instead.  [There](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/modules/Type.ts.html#unknownrecord) you will find the `UnknownRecord`.